# Three.js: Why does the obj loader doesn't work together with the mtl loader?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have a problem with loading models with three.js. I have an obj with mtl and a glb model of the same object. If i load the model with the obj and the mtl loader the object isn't shown in the browser. If i only load it with the obj loader the model is shown but without textures. If i load the model with the gltf loader there is no problem. The model is shown with the correct texture.

In addition to that i have a problem with the scale. When i load the model with the gltf loader the size of the object is different to the size of the object that is imported with the obj loader. With the obj loader the object is much bigger. (the data size is also four times bigger - so I think the problem could be the export)

**My aim is to load the Object with the obj and the mtl loader!**

Code of the obj loader:

```
const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.load( "model/test.obj", function( object ) {

    scene.add( object );
    object.scale.set(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
    object.rotateX(-Math.PI/4);
    console.log( object );

});
```

Code of the obj and the mtl loader:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load( "model/test.mtl", function( materials ) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    objLoader.load( "model/test.obj", function( object ) {
        
        scene.add( object );

    });

});
```

Code of the gltf loader:

```
const gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader( manager );
gltfLoader.load( "model/test.glb", function( gltf ) {

    model = gltf.scene;
    model.rotateX( -Math.PI/2 );
    scene.add( model );
    console.log( model );

});
```

And here is the full code:

```js
let scene, camera;

init();


// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Function init() ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
function init() {
    
    // ---------------------- General settings ----------------------
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );     
    camera.position.x = 15.6;
    camera.position.y = 18.7;
    camera.position.z = -12.3;

    const ambiLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.5 );
    scene.add(ambiLight);

    const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFFFFF, 0.6 );
    spotLight.position.set( 23.5, 10.0, 7.5 );
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    scene.add( spotLight );
    
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.load( "model/test.mtl", function( materials ) {

        materials.preload();

        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
        objLoader.load( "model/test.obj", function( object ) {
            
            scene.add( object );

        });

    });
    
    // ---------------------- Renderer settings ----------------------
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0 );

    // ---------------------- Orbit Controls settings ----------------------
    const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );  

    // ---------------------- Call functions ----------------------
    update( renderer, scene, camera, controls );

}


// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Function update() ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
function update( renderer, scene, camera, controls ) {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    controls.update();
    
    requestAnimationFrame( function() {

        update( renderer, scene, camera, controls );

    });

}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="lib/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/orbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="src/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My folder structure looks this:

[image]

And here are the OBJ and the MAT files:

[Link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar0Ww3N3hCeWgfUk-kGRZubGSqkzjA?e=ge8Igv)

Comment: Do you mind sharing the OBJ/MTL asset with all textures in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 Unfortunately this isn't possible. But I'll post my whole code in a new answer. (Don't know if this helps)

Comment: You should not share your code as an answer (this is not how stackoverflow works). Please update the question instead. I'm afraid it will be hard to investigate the issue without your assets. Why can't you share them?

Comment: @Mugen87 I edited my previous question. Now there is a picture of my folder structure and a link to the OBJ and the MTL files. Hope you can help me now

Comment: Thanks for sharing the files. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be fixed by configuring `MTLLoader` like so:

```js
new THREE.MTLLoader()
    .setMaterialOptions( { invertTrProperty: true } )
```

Your MTL contains `Tr 1.000000` values which define the opacity of materials. Unfortunately, the `Tr` value is interpreted differently across exporters/importers. In `three.js` a value of `1` means zero opacity. Hence, your asset is invisible.

The above configuration inverts the value so you end up with a fully opaque object.

Keep in mind that consistency issues like that do not appear with the well defined glTF, which should be your first choice when choosing a 3D format.